# Apex merging not working - Entity is deleted?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm receiving this error and the merge of the two contacts is not working. Any help appreciated.

Here is one of the errors I'm receiving in the logs: "23:10:48:243 EXCEPTION_THROWN [14]|System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0A1a0000095ZDxEAM; first error: ENTITY_IS_DELETED, entity is deleted: []"

Here is my class for merging (the custom fields are contact lookups):

```
public class BatchMerge implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Contact_to_Merge_Into__c, Contact__c FROM Contact_Merge_Record__c]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Contact_Merge_Record__c[] records) {
        for(Contact_Merge_Record__c record: records) {
            try {
                Database.merge(new Contact(Id=record.Contact_to_Merge_Into__c), record.Contact__c);
                record.Merge_Status__c = 'Success';
            } catch(exception e) {
                record.Merge_Status__c = 'Failed';
            }
        }
        update records;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Database.merge(new Contact(Id=record.Contact_to_Merge_Into__c), record.Contact__c);` your `record` object gets merged and deleted. You are then trying to update its status by doing `record.Merge_Status__c = 'Success';`. Clearly, if the object is already deleted, you can't change its fields.

Comment: But I'm merging the contact (contact__c), which belongs to the Contact_Merge_Record__c object. My only guess was that it goes to update the Contact_Merge_Record__c object, and tries to save the record with a reference to the pre-existing contact lookup (contact__c) which has now been merged/deleted, and it's throwing the error due to the invalid reference.  I just don't understand your explanation since I'm merging/deleted the contact__c object, not the record or Contact_Merge_Record__c. Is there a way around this, so I can update the Contact_Merge_Record__c status for success/fail?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right. You are updating `record` and it has an invalid reference to `Contact__c`. I would try simply clearing the reference before you update `record.Contact__c = NULL`

Comment: Is there anyway to keep the lookup field on the page and not null out the contact? If so, since the master contact inherits contact references, it should show the same contact after the merge. It works if I just supply a string with the ID instead of the contact itself, but just curious if you can still achieve this with references to contacts.

Comment: This fixes my issue, but it feels dirty..


                record.Contact__c = record.Contact_to_Merge_Into__c;           
                record.Merge_Status__c = 'Successfly merged';
                update record;
               
         //
                record.Contact__c = null;
                record.Merge_Status__c = 'Failed to merge';
                update record;